# How can I use emojis in Outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, unicode

Is there any way to use emojis in Outlook 2007?

I'm an emoji-speaking man using old software that won't let me communicate in my native language. Please help! ‍

Comment: Besides third-party plugins or clipart, I do not believe Outlook 2007 support emojis.

Comment: I don't recall emojis being a thing at the time Outlook 2007 came out.  But some links: [Apparently limited support until Office 2016 (famous "J" issue)](https://office-watch.com/2017/outlook-discovers-emoji-goodbye-j-hello-color-smiley/).  Workarounds: [1](https://office-watch.com/2015/using-emoji-in-microsoft-office/), [2](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1776-outlook-insert-smiley-face.html), [3](http://www.msoutlooktools.com/category/options/4/).